# Executing PostgreSQL stored procedure that returns an integer

Tags: php, postgresql, plpgsql

I have a stored procedure that returns an integer, and I need to execute it from PHP.
The problem is that I don't know how to retrieve the result.

I'm executing the stored procedure this way:

```
$result = pg_query($con, "SELECT stored_procedure('$param1', '$param2')");
```

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Retrieve the result the same way you'd retrieve any other select results. Your data will come back looking tabular, with one row and one column.